# How to call a C mehod of JNI in another C task?

Tags: c, java-native-interface, gdb, valgrind

I had implemented a JNI method for processing an object and returning a value.

This method is a little bit complex and has a lot of JNI allocations.

I want to debug my JNI method using GDB and check its memory using Valgrind, but using javam this task sounds complicated.

So my question is, is it possible to create a C function that calls a JNI function close to how java would call?

like this example:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_test_Test_func (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring jstr){
    const char *p_str;
    p_str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jstr, 0);
    return char[2];
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    JNIEnv env;
    jstring test = env->NewStringUTF(env, "vals");
    printf("%d\n", Java_test_Test_func(&env, NULL, test));
    //Expects: 108
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest that you move the complex part of the method into a separate C function. Write test code in C to test it. The JNI method can just convert the java parameters and call the C function. Unless the complexity of the code is mostly related to the JNI interface rather than the actual work the code is doing, this should be a better way to develop, test, and debug the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to actually create the VM first, see [Chapter 5 of the JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502).
This will give you a `jvm` from which you can grab a `JNIEnv *env` and call your function.

That said, you can also just start your Java process normally, attach a debugger to it and put a breakpoint on your function as you would with any other native program.